# Filter an array for url validation

Tags: php, arrays

[image]
I made a form where people posts fname, lname, products and links. I did validation for names and product and links. Now the thing if someone posting adult or fraud or scam links then i also want to filter that out. I spent hours on this and cant find anything on internet. Now i decide to do this and write a some code on my own. I studied some thing in php manual and there i found to filter the array thats array_filter. On [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) With the reference of "rolf" notes there I found how to delete specific value from an array.

Now the thing is when i integrate this with my server side code the filter array also show with the users array and when i type the filter array the string is going to delete and array is empty. I am not very good with explanation so i also post a pic for better understanding whats going on.

What i want is filter array value not come until it has been called if the filter value array called then its going to delete the specific value from array. OR You guys have better solution

If the array is matched then say the user Good bye or Thanks your link posted now.

php

```
[if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        echo "What are you doing MAN !! Try Again..";
    } else {
        echo "Thanks! You do a great JOB!";
    }

    $array = array ("bad.com"); 


$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function ($element) use ($name) { return ($element != $name); } ); 
print_r($filtered_array);
}
```